How many pixels are there in a vector tile from TomTom?
In order to convert the coordinates of the geometries in a vector tile from TomTom, you need to know how many pixels are there in a tile. The documentation states that:

The extent is equal to 4096, so the value range for X and Y coordinates is from 0 to 4095.

But, another part of the documentation shows that meters/tile side is 40075017 and meters/pixel is 156543 at the zoom level 0.  If you do the division, it comes to be about 256, which seems to indicate that each tile is 256 x 256.
So, which is it?
Tried to create a conversion method like following, but unsure if it's correct:
    public static double[] convertFromLocalToGlobal(int x, int y, int tileX, int tileY, int zoom) {
        double earthCircumference = 40075017.0;
        int numTiles = 1 << zoom;  // 2^zoom
        double tileSize = earthCircumference / numTiles;
        double originX = tileX * tileSize;
        double originY = tileY * tileSize;
        // I'm assuming 256 pixels per tile side because the documentation shows
        // 40075017 metres for a tile side and 156543 metres for a pixel at zoom level 0
        double posX = originX + x * (tileSize / 256); 
        double posY = originY + y * (tileSize / 256);
        // Convert meters to global coordinates
        double lon = (posX / earthCircumference) * 360.0 - 180.0;
        
        double normalizedY = posY / earthCircumference;
        double mercatorY = Math.PI * (1 - 2 * normalizedY);
        double lat = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(Math.sinh(mercatorY)));

        return new double[]{lat, lon};
    }

